# Angular is modifying scope within method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infinite-loop

I have a method being called inside my scope which performs a calculation on the model that you pass through.

This is causing an infinite loop because Angular is modifying the original object, not the local copy of it in the method.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <ul ng-controller="TodoController">
        <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">{{ todo.name }} {{ doSomething(todo) }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('TodoController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.todos = [{
        name:      'Todo 1',
        someValue: 1
    }];

    $scope.doSomething = function (todo) {
        console.log(todo.someValue);
        todo.someValue += 1;
        return todo.someValue;
    };

}]);
```

See this in action here https://jsfiddle.net/pvkpj169/
If you open up the console while running this you will see that it causes an infinite loop.

How can I prevent Angular for modifying the original model within this scope? I want any changes made in here to be local to the method

Comment: `var localVal = todo.someValue;`
`localVal += 1;`
 `return localVal;`

do you mean to create a local copy ?

Comment: This is due to how angular digest cycle works. If scope changes within one digest another digest occurs. This continues until scope is stable. You keep adding `todo.someValue += 1;` each digest so it will be infinite. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your doSomething() is making the model unstable by adding a new copy of your todo.

Use the following controller code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('TodoController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.todos = [{
    name: 'Todo 1',
    someValue: 1
  }];

  $scope.doSomething = function(todo) {
    console.log(todo.someValue);
    var val = todo.someValue + 1;
    return val;
  };

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it was me I would get rid of the function completely and change:

```
{{ doSomething(todo) }}
```

to:

```
{{ todo.someValue + 1 }}
```

Angular will evaluate this for you in the view and the digests won't keep incrementing the object property value